# Lambda Management getting timed out

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm trying to build a Alexa skill in python. And for the same I compressed all my files into a zip. But when I try to upload the *zip file* to lambda I'm getting this error:

> timeout of 61000ms exceeded

And I'm not even able to save my files to lambda Management.
I tried deleting the function and recreating another but no help. I even tried making another account for the same purpose but still not getting anywhere.
Is there any bug in aws lambda management for python runtime? or is it my code? (But I'm not even able to execute my code).[image: screen shot of Lambda Management]

Comment: This appears to be an error the console is throwing, that is related to an internal timer in the code that runs the console itself.  I encountered a similar error today while doing nothing other than looking at a function version in the console, but the suspiciously non-round-number value of 61000ms timeout was displayed.  There are currently reports of connectivity issues in us-east-1, but this should not have been the case at the time you posted the question.

Comment: Actually, I've been facing this issue 1 day prior to the day I posted this question. I too thought that it must be a temporary issue, but It didn't seem to be getting of, so I thought of asking a question here.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I also tried to upload my zip to S3 bucket and save the link to my lambda management. But I'm still getting this error. What should I do?

Comment: You might try using aws-cli's [`aws lambda update-function-code`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html) capability.  Intuition tells me there may be some quirky edge case bugs in the Lambda console right now.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue while doing this.
I had to increase the timeout to rectify it.
However, I would suggest that you use `S3` for zip file storage and the provide the `S3 URL` on the Lambda Management Console.

Set the timeout as in the following screenshot

[image: Lambda Basic Settings]

**OR**

Upload to `S3` first and give the `S3 URL` as follow

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that these settings are for my lambda management console and not for the execution of my lambda function?.
And moreover the timeout already present was **3 sec**, and the error I'm getting is for **61 sec**.

Comment: @NikhilWagh I know these settings are not related to uploading files, however I have multiple Lambdas and in each of those I faced the same issue and it was around a month ago, so changing this setting everytime resolved the issue.